# Using Neon.tech Postgres DB with a Strapi Application

Tags: postgresql, strapi, pg, neon.tech

I'm trying to setup up a deployed Strapi V4 application with Neon.tech's Postgres database. I set up the DATABASE_URL correctly and checked that all the environment variables were being read appropriately. However, the app crashes with a 500 status code every time I try to load my admin dashboard.

Is there something I'm missing that makes them incompatible?

Comment: any luck?  i was going to attempt the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a Strapi plugin for usage of neon.tech DB: https://github.com/trieb-work/strapi-neon-tech-db-branches

The Plugin will set the DB URL automatically and will also create new DB branches as soon as you git checkout into a new branch. This feature is very usefull for preview deployments in a later stage, because you can preview deploy from this new DB branch and do not need to seed with testing data to get a real deployment.
More on this here: https://trieb.work/blog/article/neontech-serverless-postgres-db-strapi-auto-branching-plugin
(German only sorry... but with deepl.com you should be able to get a decent translation)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know about the strapi, but for the sequelize the link that neon provides also didn’t work for me

try to modify it with sslmode param

```
postgres://<DB_USERNAME>:<DB_PASS>@<DB_ENDPOINT>.<DB_HOST>/<DB_NAME>?sslmode=require`
```

Comment: Can confirm this solution is correct (tested myself). Faced some issues since the password had been reset earlier, so my connection string was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Strapi config that works with Neon db:

```
DATABASE_CLIENT=postgres
DATABASE_HOST=*******.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_NAME=neondb
DATABASE_USERNAME=******
DATABASE_PASSWORD=********
DATABASE_SSL=true
DATABASE_POOL_MIN=0
DATABASE_POOL_MAX=15
DATABASE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=1000000
```

Comment: This is one solution